# How to Call back data from child Activity and make the images in parent activity transparent

Tags: android, gridview, sharedpreferences

I have images in gridview. These images are shown in an activity. When one of the images is clicked, new activity is started with this image. In this activity, If user inputs correct answer, new activity is started that indicates the answer is correct. After user inputs correct answer, I want to set this image more transparent with a check mark in gridwiew.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);
    initComponent();
    gva.setAdapter(new ImageAdaptera(getApplicationContext()));

    gva.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
int position, long id) {
  switch (position) {

            case 0:

              {

                    Intent intenta = new Intent (getBaseContext(),     AA.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    startActivityForResult(intenta,0);

                }

                break;

            case 1:
            {
                Intent intentb = new Intent (getBaseContext(), AB.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivityForResult(intentb,0);
            }
               break;


      case 2:
    {
        Intent intentc = new Intent (getBaseContext(), AC.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivityForResult(intentc,0);
    }
   break;
   }}
```

}

My Image Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageViewa; 
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageViewa = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageViewa.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageViewa.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageViewa.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageViewa = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageViewa.setImageResource(imagesa[position]);


    return imageViewa;

}
```

Child Activity:

```
       @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                 if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                String check = input.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
                Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
                editor.putString(GAME_PREFERENCES_answeraa, check);
                editor.commit();



                if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("petronet")){

                    display.setText("correct");
                    Toast.makeText(AA.this,"CORRECT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent data = new Intent();
                    // TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);         
input.setEnabled(false);Guruapp.levela++;Guruapp.count++;
int hc2 = mGameSettings.getInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_hint, Guruapp.count);
Guruapp.count = hc2;

finish();

                }           


                else{
                    display.setText("Wrong");
                    Toast.makeText(AA.this,"WRONG",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make:

1. a public static ArrayList imageResponded=new ArrayList(numberOfImages);
2. set the imageResponded arrayList elements to false
3. then when the user choose an image, you take that image's index to know what image to show in your next activity
4. when the user inputs the correct answer regarding of the image showed you
5. when you return in your grid view activity, in onResume when you recreate the grid view with images, before you place the image in a box you check first if on that index the imageResponded.get(index) return true, if it does you set the alpha of image on 75% and put a tick in lower right of the image

Comment: no one is there to answer, is my question wrong or is SO dead

Comment: where to create the arraylist... is it in image adapter

Comment: Sorry but I don't have time to write your code... I explained you my idea for the algorithm, I saw that you know how to handle the Android, even if you are new in this. I don't think that someone from SO will resolve your problems, they will help you to understand how to do it. If I had some time I would help you to understand how to write code, but I am sorry, I don't have that time. Eventually in the weekend :)

Comment: please do understand, I donot want the entire code, i just want to know where to provide the array list is it in gridview.java (or) image adapter. How to get the index no from child activity,